# Can I equip the space $H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$ with a $L^2( \partial \Omega)$ inner product?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Since the space $H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$ with its norm $\Vert u \Vert_{H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)} = \inf_{v \in H^1(\Omega),  v\vert_{\partial \Omega} = u} \Vert v \Vert_{H^1(\Omega)}$ gets unhandy in numerical computations, I would like to know, if I can equip this space with the inner product of the space $L^2( \partial \Omega)$.

2) side question: Is there any chance, I can get $\Vert u \Vert_{H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)} \leq C \Vert u \Vert_{L^2(\partial \Omega)}$?

Comment: You can certainly do this, the question is just if it serves your purpose. The resulting space is incomplete, for example, and the inequality (2) does not hold.

Comment: Ok, thank you .

Answer (score 0):

For numerical computation, maybe you can try another definition of $H^{\frac 1 2}(\partial\Omega)$, see  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2311227 .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).